# Create Custom Week Of Field SQL -- Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, date

This is for a query in Oracle 12c

I'm trying to create a "Week Of" field that will use the date field present in the record to assign that record a Week Of date that reflects the start of a week. I want the start of weeks to be Sundays and the end of weeks to be Saturdays.

To give an example of what I mean:

```
metric_date        metric        value        week_of
01-oct-20          sales         45           27-sep-20
05-oct-20          sales         15           04-oct-20
```

Where the week of field is always the most recent sunday date. I have tried to modify this SQL Server code to work in Oracle, as it was written for a similar purpose:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Order Date]) % 7, [Order Date]) AS [Week of]
FROM dbo.your_table_name
```

Here is my attempt at replicating the code in Oracle:

```
SELECT distinct
metric_date,
mod(-(to_date('01-jan-1900','dd-mon-yyyy') - trunc(metric_date)),7) + metric_date as week_of

FROM dbo.table
```

But it does not return the results I want.
Are there any obvious differences you can see that I am not accounting for in my replicated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `next_day()`:

```
select t.*, next_day(metric_date - 7, 'sunday')
from mytable t
```

Note that the second argument to `next_day()` is language-dependent. If your database is configured in another language than English, use the local translation of Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRUNC` with the `IW` option (which is independent of the language) to truncate the date to Monday and then shift the values by 1 day:

```sql
SELECT metric_date,
       TRUNC( metric_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'IW' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
         AS sunday_of_week
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( metric_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-10-01' + LEVEL - 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 14;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> METRIC_DATE | SUNDAY_OF_WEEK
> :---------- | :-------------
> 01-OCT-20   | 27-SEP-20     
> 02-OCT-20   | 27-SEP-20     
> 03-OCT-20   | 27-SEP-20     
> 04-OCT-20   | 04-OCT-20     
> 05-OCT-20   | 04-OCT-20     
> 06-OCT-20   | 04-OCT-20     
> 07-OCT-20   | 04-OCT-20     
> 08-OCT-20   | 04-OCT-20     
> 09-OCT-20   | 04-OCT-20     
> 10-OCT-20   | 04-OCT-20     
> 11-OCT-20   | 11-OCT-20     
> 12-OCT-20   | 11-OCT-20     
> 13-OCT-20   | 11-OCT-20     
> 14-OCT-20   | 11-OCT-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b748f8f2a9a5600e760008956ab0340)*